# xymatrix is broken when inside section

Tags: hyperref, xy-pic

If I use `xymatrix` inside of a `section` command, it doesn't compile.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}

\section{$\xymatrix{A\ar[r]&B}$}

\end{document}
```

Compilation error: `Argument of doSpecialRotate@@ has an extra {`.

I found a proposed solution at the end of [this discussion](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/EW100uTBCA8ZBf7xF2lF). Problem is, I have found it to collapse when I use either the bookmark package or the hyperref package. Now, the bookmark package I can dispose of, but the hyperref package is vital for me. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ta}{\xymatrix{A\ar[r]&B}}
\section{A stepping stone: $\ta$}

\end{document}
```

Compilation error: `Argument of \xP@rotate@ has an extra }`. If you comment out the line concerning hyperref, it works correctly.

How can I use both an `xymatrix` command inside a `\section` and use the hyperref package?

Comment: You try to use mathematical markup in a section command, which will try to set up a bookmark with math content. As far as I know, this does not work. If it is possible, I would like to know how it works ;-) You could use `\section{\unexpanded{A stepping stone: $\ta$}}` to bypass the error message, however

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not just write $A\to B$ in the title instead, why the need for `\xymatrix`?

Comment: @daleif: a very reasonable question. The thing is I don't want to use just a plain arrow, I want a more fancy arrow that I only know how to render with `xymatrix`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: it works on the MWE I posted above (the second one). On my actual document, it works for the first compilation but fails on the second one, something toc-related.

Comment: I'd still just use `\longrightarrow` as @egreg shows below, the A to B does not stand on the same line as the rest of the text, which looks bad in my book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have typesetting instructions in the bookmarks; moreover you need to protect the fragile commands in `\xymatrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\protectedtexorpdfstring}[2]{%
  \texorpdfstring{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A stepping stone: \protectedtexorpdfstring{\xymatrix{A\ar[r]&B}}{A\textrightarrow B}}

\end{document}
```

In the second argument of `\protectedtexorpdfstring` (choose a shorter name, if you wish) you put an approximate representation of the diagram or anything you prefer.

[image]

If you plan to also have a table of contents, there's something more to be done; the problem is that when the `.toc` file is read in, the category code of `@` is 11, which confuses `xypic`.

The `\txymatrix` command has two arguments: the contents of the `\xymatrix` and the alternative text for the bookmark.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\protectedtexorpdfstring}[2]{%
  \texorpdfstring{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\txymatrix}[2]{%
  \protectedtexorpdfstring
    {$\catcode`\@=12 \scantokens{\xymatrix{#1}}$}
    {#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A stepping stone: \txymatrix{A\ar[r]&B}{A\textrightarrow B}}

\section{A stepping stone: \txymatrix{K\Omega \ar@{~}[r]^-\simeq & KqB^b}{KOmega}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, when I use the decorated arrow I wanted to use, it shows up very badly in the TOC. `\section{A stepping stone: \protectedtexorpdfstring{\xymatrix{K\Omega \ar@{~}[r]^-\simeq & KqB^b}}{KOmega}}`. That is, passing the `\tableofcontents` command. How can I fix this?

Comment: @egreg: Good answer! Is the slight downshift of the typeset `\xymatrix` command in the section head or in TOC reversable?

Comment: @BrunoStonek Fixed.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Enclosing `\xymatrix` between `$` symbols does it.